# I get a blank page until a session cookie is set - PHP 4.4.9

Tags: php, session, php4

The first time I visit, I get a blank page - no text whotsoever if i click "view source", but a session cookie is added.
The second, everything runs as it should.
If I delete the cookie, I get a blank page again.
Same in all browsers - Firefox 4, IE 9, Chrome 11.
PHP 4.4.9

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "hello";
?>
```

**Update:**

```
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user 

session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /tmp    /tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   On  On
```

This is my phpinfo on sessions
I've already tried ini_set("display_errors", 1);
I've also tried setting ini_set('error_log') to a file in a folder that is writable, but I don't get any errors (even if I write "asdfasdf(asdf(0)}" as the first line.)

Comment: Is there no possibility for you to update to a newer PHP version?

Comment: turn on error checking, there will be errors you just are not seeing them.

Comment: It's not my server, so I can't update. In any case I doubt that a version of PHP would be released, that would give such an obvious error. I've tried adding, "error_reporting(E_ALL);" before session_start(), but I still get just a blank page

Comment: add: error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: What information does phpinfo() show regarding sessions? Anything obviously wrong?

Comment: made an update on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with your php.ini

I would check the "session.save_path" and "session.use_cookies" entries and the directories referenced (permissions etc). Also use phpinfo() to spot configuration errors.

Comment: Can you try changing session.use_only_cookies to On. Also is /tmp a valid path on the server with all relevant privileges and enough free space? Can you clear all the existing sessions?

Comment: Also have you had a look in your error log to see if anything is being written when you access the page?

Comment: I've added
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 'On'); 
as the first line, it works now.
Still, I am curious what was the problem? + Don't know how to access the error log
phpinfo says 
error_log no value, if that's of any help

Comment: It will be hard to tell without being able to view the actual errors being generated, but forcing cookies isn't a bad thing as it prevents attacks involving session IDs in the URL. I presume you are using Apache? If so you could try looking in /var/log/httpd/error_log

Comment: Yes, it's apache. It's a public server, I doubt that I have the necessary privileges. I'll google to find if there is a way I can get an error log. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

as a workaround, check for the session before you start it and refresh/redirect the page imediately after you start it

Comment: That would work, but I would prefer a "cleaner" solution if possible